# Setting up Relationship types in GrandStack

Tags: javascript, neo4j, graphql, grandstack

I am trying to setup a relationship type in Grandstack. I am having issues getting things to run correctly.  Even when I copy the guide into my project and try to run it ... things do not work. Here is what they have at https://grandstack.io/docs/guide-graphql-schema-design

```
type Actor {
    actorId: ID!
    name: String
    movies: [Movie] @relation(name: "ACTED_IN", direction: OUT)
}

type Movie {
    movieId: ID!
    title: String
    description: String
    year: Int
    actors(limit: Int = 10): [Actor] @relation(name: "ACTED_IN", direction: IN)
    similarMovies(limit: Int = 10): [Movie] @cypher(statement: """
        MATCH (this)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(:Actor)-[:ACTED_IN]->(rec:Movie)
        WITH rec, COUNT(*) AS score ORDER BY score DESC
        RETURN rec LIMIT $limit
    """)
}

type User {
    userId: ID!
    name: String
    rated: [Rated]
}

type Rated @relation(name: "RATED") {
    from: User
    to: Movie
    rating: Float
    review: String
}
```

The problem is when I run this I get the following error:

```
ApolloError: The 'from' argument of the @relation directive on the _UserRated type is "User", but a "User" field is not defined.
    at validateRelationTypeNodeField (/Users/kennyv/git/skoutal-server/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/augment/types/relationship/relationship.js:221:13)
    at validateRelationTypeDirective (/Users/kennyv/git/skoutal-server/node_modules/neo4j-graphql-js/dist/augment/types/relationship/relationship.js:183:5)
```

Not sure why it thinks the User field is not defined.
Here is my server.js file

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { ApolloServer, PubSub } = require("apollo-server");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");
const { augmentSchema, makeAugmentedSchema } = require("neo4j-graphql-js");
const typeDefs = require("./graphql/typeDefs.js");
const resolvers = require("./graphql/resolvers");

require("console-stamp")(console, { pattern: "mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:ss.l" });
// Create an instance of Express

const pubsub = new PubSub();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const schema = makeAugmentedSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  // config: {
  //   query: true,
  //   mutation: true,
  // },
});
const augmentedSchema = augmentSchema(schema);

const driver = neo4j.driver(
  process.env.NEO4J_URI || "bolt://localhost:7687",
  neo4j.auth.basic(
    process.env.NEO4J_USER || "neo4j",
    process.env.NEO4J_PASSWORD || "neo4j"
  )
);

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: schema,
  context: ({ req }) => {
    const token = req?.headers?.authorization?.slice(7);
    let userId;
    if (token) {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.APP_SECRET);
      userId = decoded.id;
    }
    return {
      cypherParams: { userId },
      driver,
      neo4jDatabase: process.env.NEO4J_DATABASE,
      req,
      pubsub,
    };
  },
});
```

```
"apollo-server": "^2.20.0",
"graphql": "^15.5.0",
"neo4j-driver": "^4.2.2",
"neo4j-graphql-js": "^2.19.2",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accidentally running

```
const augmentedSchema = augmentSchema(schema);
```

on a schema that I had already ran

```
makeAugmentedSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  // config: {
  //   query: true,
  //   mutation: true,
  // },
});
```

This was an artifact of moving away from makeExecutableSchema which I had to remove because it was causing issues.

namely:

```
Error: Unknown directive "@relation".

Unknown directive "@relation".

Unknown directive "@cypher".

Unknown directive "@relation".

Unknown directive "@relation".

Unknown directive "@relation".
```

So when i commented out the augmentSchema things started working fine.